# Cannot set spellchecker on Tecno Camon 19 Pro

Tags: android-13, spell-check, tecno

The phone is Tecno Camon 19 Pro.
The system is Android 13 (HIOS 13).

In Language settings, selecting spellchecker opens a menu. The menu has Gboard, but tapping on it does nothing. Still, the spellchecker method is not selected. Gboard settings ask to set system spellchecker first.

[image: Screenshot]

Maybe I need to enable some hidden settings?